# Permutations on word $MISSISSIPPI$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can the letters of the word $MISSISSIPPI$ be rearranged ?

I am confused on whether it is  $\dfrac{11!}{4!4!2!}$ or $\dfrac{11!}{4!4!2!}-1$

since it is given *rearranged* and not *arranged*.

Comment: Those words are usually treated as equivalent for the purposes of such questions (and so the answer would be the former, larger number), but unless you are forced to provide a single numerical value, I see no harm in providing both answers, with justification.

Comment: I would assume that they are expecting the first answer,  but I wouldn't expect you to lose points for either.

Comment: @BrianTung: These are objective type questions, I need to provide only one answer with options given.

Comment: In that case, I would offer the first answer.  If they really meant to avoid all respellings, I think they would have explicitly said so.

Comment: If it gives options, it will surely give as a possible answer, only **one** of the two interpretations !

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{11!}{4!4!2!} -1 $$

since $\frac{11!}{4!4!2!}$ is the total number of permutations of the letters from the word **MISSISSIPPI**.

Since, the word itself is not a rearrangement of itself, that's why a "-1"

Comment: But then there are more to subtract, since many leave the same word MISSISSIPPI in that order. [It is vague, in that does it mean rearrange the physical letters, or just rearrange the positions of the same letters]

Comment: @coffee: In such problems, permutations of identical letters don't count, so subtracting 1 (if, indeed, it needs to be subtracted) is correct.

Comment: the divison by 4!4!2! is done to remove such repetitions.